# Angular - how to navigate to a different page when the application starts keeping maintainability in mind

Tags: angular, routes, nativescript

I'm writing an app with Angular 8+ and NativeScript 6+.

By default, my app opens to a landing page.

What I want to happen is when the app loads, if the user is logged in the app will re-direct them to the home page instead of the landing page.

How can I do this properly?

I've considered the following approaches:

1. land on the default page, check the authentication credentials and then route to the home page. This might happen in ngInit
2. use route guards - I don't know how to implement it to get it to work how I want.

What's the maintainable approach?

Comment: 1. would not be maintainable, as you would potentially be redirecting users who wanted to stay on the default page. Maybe they've opened it in a new tab from an existing session? 2. is the way to go.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on how to use route guards, and they're pretty simple once you start to understand them.

Comment: @KurtHamilton thanks. I'm new to route guards. Is it possible to re-direct while checking the route?

Comment: You can run an observable which will delay the loading of the route. In your case, you would return true if the user is logged in to allow the route to load, or the url to redirect to - the home page

Answer (score 2):

Implementing the Authguard is the best approach as you will need to guard many of your components.

One tutorial i read - https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular CanActivate Guard. Check this [example](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-canactivate-guard-example/)

Also read [this](https://codeburst.io/using-angular-route-guard-for-securing-routes-eabf5b86b4d1) about AuthGuards